# assign export.json() to new variable

Tags: python

In python im using requests library.

```
    payload = {'Code':Code}
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
    export = requests.post('http://service-one.vms.svc.cluster.local/api/done/v1/import/company', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print(export.json())
```

output is:

```
{'id': 'dcc515e0-8c43-4e2a-871b-99fcc4fd4403'}
```

How can I assign only "value" part from this key:value to new variable so I can use it later?

Comment: It's a regular dictionary: `export.json()["id"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `export.json()` gives you a dictionary. To save only the value to a variable you can do

```
exported_value = export.json()["id"]
```

`get()` will give you the same result too

```
exported_value = export.json().get("id")
```

I suggest to check [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in Python